# How to set up a PFQuery to get all users with a given role using queryForTable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I’m using Parse’s PFUser and PFRole classes. Now I need to list users with a specific role in a UITableView, which appears to be a fairly simple task.

So I’ve created a PFQueryTableViewController and overridden `queryForTable()` inside of which I’ve tried to first get the role, then its users:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let roleQuery: PFQuery? = PFRole.query()
    roleQuery!.whereKey("name", equalTo: "admin")

    var userQuery: PFQuery?

    roleQuery!.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            let role: PFRole? = object as? PFRole
            let relation: PFRelation? = role!.relationForKey("users")

            userQuery = relation!.query()
        }
    }

    return userQuery!
}
```

But since `getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock()` is asynchronous, the query that’s supposed to be returned is always nil. I also tried with `getFirstObject()`, which is synchronous, but in this case I get the following warning: *A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.*

I’m sure there must be a simple way to set up this query… Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance!

David

Comment: Run the role query first and then load the table when it's ready so you have all the details required to create the query

Comment: Hi @Wain, thank you for the fast answer. How would you run the role query _then_ load the table? I tried to run it inside the init() method but I get the following error: _The class PFRole must be registered with registerSubclass before using Parse_.

Comment: Is this your root view controller? Best to get the role on the previous screen and pass it in, adding a new splash screen for this if required.

Comment: @Wain: yes, this is the initial view controller… Okay I'll try that! Thank you again for your help! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with Parse and asynchronous queries and I've solved it differently. 
You could use closure in the function that calls the download function in your view controller. 
E.g. when you start downloading the data, show an activity indicator on your table view, and in case the search has ended and was successful in the

```
if error == nil { //here you can populate your table in your view by using a closure function }
```

Here is a link to documentation on how to use closures:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103

Comment: Hi @Shelin, thank you for your answer. The problem is that queryForTable() itself shouldn’t execute the query but simply “build” and return it…

Comment: Ok, so how do you want to proceed when you get the query? You want to do other things and later load the data you've got from the query to the table? Do you have a variable in your viewcontroller that you want to bind the query to?

Comment: Hi @Shelin: from what I know, you can’t explicitly execute the query when using PFQueryTableViewController… You just specify it using the `queryForTable()` method and the controller then uses it to fetch data from Parse when needed. So, I don’t see how to “do other things” before this query is run.